# How can I render a image with a certain field of view?

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage

Good evening! I have successfully displayed an image using java and the graphics object.
This is my 'Renderer'-Class:

```
public class Renderer {

    private static BufferStrategy bs;
    private static Graphics g;
    private static Window win;

    public static final int MIN_BUFFER_COUNT = 1;
    public static final int MAX_BUFFER_COUNT = 4;

    public static void prepareRenderer(BufferStrategy bs) {
        Renderer.bs = bs;
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    }

    public static BufferStrategy createBufferStrategy(Window window, int bufferCount) {
        if(window.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy() == null) {
            window.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(bufferCount);
        }
        win = window;
        BufferStrategy _bs = window.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
        return _bs;
    }

    public static void clearWindow(Window window) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());
    }

    public static void drawRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public static void setColor(Color color) {
        g.setColor(color);
    }

    public static void drawImage(BufferedImage image, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, win.getWidth() / width * Config.getField_of_view(),  win.getHeight() / height * Config.getField_of_view(), null);
    }

    public static void drawSprite(Sprite sprite, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), x, y, (int) (win.getWidth() / width * Config.getField_of_view()), (int) (win.getHeight() / height * Config.getField_of_view()), null);
    }

    public static void closeRenderer() {
        bs.show();
        g.dispose();
    }
```

I made this strange code in the renderer because I want to have a certain field of view no matter what window size.
This is what I wrote in the Main-Class:

```
    @Override
    public void render() {
        //Prepare
        Renderer.prepareRenderer(Renderer.createBufferStrategy(window, Renderer.MAX_BUFFER_COUNT));
        //Clear
        Renderer.clearWindow(window);
        //Draw
        Renderer.drawSprite(sprite, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        //Close
        Renderer.closeRenderer();
    }
```

But now I have a problem because when I make the window into a rectangle it looks pretty stretched.

Comment: I don't think you want to multiply the height and width of your input sprite with different values. As you multiply the width with the window's width, and height with window's height, it has to become stretched according to the window's dimensions (regardless of any scale factor). Try multiplying both with `Math.min(win.getWidth(), win.getHeight())` instead.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked with `Math.min(win.getWidth(), win.getHeight())` thanks